# ArXiv queries not working with ServiceConnect

Tags: webservices, serviceexecute

Support for interactive with ArXiv's apis was added in 10.2, but now as of 10.3.1 the most basic example in the documentation seems to fail:

[image]

Is this a known issue/bug, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Is it just me or are many of the ServiceConnect and friend functions very buggy?

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Win 10 V10.3.1, works well.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, can anyone replicate on OS X?

Comment: I can't reproduce on OS X. What version of OS X are you using? 
1. First try typing out this code in a new notebook after restarting the kernel by running Quit. Please type out the code. Don't cut and paste it.  Please also don't type it out in the documentation. Use a notebook. Does it behave the same?
2. Maybe something is wrong with the paclet: what is the output of `Needs["PacletManager`"];PacletInformation["ServiceConnection_ArXiv"]`

Comment: I'm using 10.3.1. There is the output from a notebook with your commands: `{"Name" -> "ServiceConnection_ArXiv", "Version" -> "0.0.8", 
 "BuildNumber" -> "", "Qualifier" -> "", "WolframVersion" -> "10+", 
 "SystemID" -> All, "Description" -> "", "Category" -> "", 
 "Creator" -> "", "Publisher" -> "", "Support" -> "", 
 "Internal" -> False, 
 "Location" -> 
  "/Users/user/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/ArXiv", 
 "Context" -> {"Arxiv`"}, "Enabled" -> True, "Loading" -> Manual}`

Comment: I just executed the same Documentation Center example code as you post on my system and I got a dataset containing four articles. I'm running V10.3.1 on OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the problem the user is experiencing can not be reproduced by others.

Comment: @m_goldberg how does that help anything

Comment: How does it help anyone (including you) to keep a question open when no one can reproduce the issue? When the problem can't be reproduce no answers are possible.

Comment: Someone might be able to reproduce it

Comment: Can you post the output of SystemInformation["Small"] please? Also, go to Edit> Preferences > Internet Connectivity and click the Update Local Indices from the Wolfram Research Server button and try again